# How to uninstall Windows 8?

Tags: installation, uninstall

I do not want to dual-boot, I want my PC to solely run Ubuntu. How can I do this? I've tried everything and it just won't work.

I am currently running Windows 8 and want to run Ubuntu 12.10. I've tried to install and run GParted, and it won't run. I've also tried uninstalling Ubuntu (actually, I restored my system to default, since I have all my files backed up on my server) and then loading it via USB. I'm at my wits end here! Please help.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to "uninstall" Windows.

I assume you're installing Ubuntu using a USB stick.

1. Boot off of the stick, and when it presents this screen:

   [image]
2. Select the **Install Ubuntu** option. Then, in the partitioning step:

   [image]
3. Select the option to **Replace Windows with Ubuntu**. The Ubuntu installer will then overwrite your Windows installation, and set up Ubuntu's bootloader (GRUB) to boot into Ubuntu.

*Images from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest*

Comment: @Erica If this worked for you, you can mark it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I started with the wubi install, then tried booting from USB and that also didn't work. 
One thing you can try is to access your system BIOS and make sure that both your CD-ROM drive and the USB are higher in the boot order than your system hard drive.
Try booting from the USB again.
If this also fails (as it did for me) you will have to mount an image of the Ubuntu ISO onto a CD or DVD. To do this in windows... download the file, then right click it and select "open with..." then there should be an option that says something to the effect of "Burn Disc Image" or "Disc Image Burner". Select that and Windows will write the ISO onto the disc. Then restart the computer and you should be able to boot from the disc.

Failing all of this, you could always smash it with a hammer.... but this worked for me.